# Javascript Callback Or Return String

Tags: javascript, string, asynchronous, callback, return

I was wondering wich of the following is the right thing to do, or which one is faster?

I have a function which generates a HTML string and gives it back.

How should I return this string that I generate, with a callback or just return it?

```
MyApp.prototype.makeChatMsg = function(message, callback) {

   var html = '<div class="media">';
   html += '<div class="media-body">';
   //html += '<h4 class="media-heading">' + message.user.first_name + ' ' + message.user.last_name + '</h4>';
   html += '<p>' + message.content + '</p>';
   html += '</div>';
   html += '</div>';

   callback(html); // see here
}
```

vs

```
MyApp.prototype.makeChatMsg = function(message) {

   var html = '<div class="media">';
   html += '<div class="media-body">';
   //html += '<h4 class="media-heading">' + message.user.first_name + ' ' + message.user.last_name + '</h4>';
   html += '<p>' + message.content + '</p>';
   html += '</div>';
   html += '</div>';

   return html; // see here
}
```

Im using these functions like this within MyApp scope

First method

```
this.makeChatMsg(incomingMessage, function(html) {
    $('#messages').append(html); 
));
```

Second method

```
var newMessage = this.makeChatMsg(incomingMessage);
$('#messages').append(newMessage);
```

Generating a HTML string is this a asynchronous task or not? Im just not sure..

Comment: As it's not async, I would just return it.

Answer (score 2):

Generally we should `return` from a function and avoid `callbacks`.

What I think callback is meant for when you have to use `non-blocking` or `asynchronous` call like an AJAX request. There every thing would be done with a `callback`

Because there you don't know when your task will be finished, so if you want to perform something after finishing that task, we use callback.

I'd say `return` is better that `callback`. If there are too many callbacks they result out as [callback pyramid](http://tritarget.org/blog/2012/11/28/the-pyramid-of-doom-a-javascript-style-trap/).

Comment: is there a performance issue if I keep using those callbacks, does it create a new thread or something?

Comment: @webmaster I don't think there is a performance issue, in javascript there is nothing called as thread.

Answer (score 1):

Go with the simpler solution, returning the string, until you have a reason to do something more complicated.

From what I can see, makeChatMsg will run extremely quickly. No reason for it to run asynchronously.